# set edittext enabled/disabled

Tags: android, spinner

I've an interface. In this interface I've a spinner with 2 values: Browser and Chart. When I select Browser I want another editText called eTxtUrl is enabled. When I select Chart I want this EditText is disabled.

This is my code:

```
    spinnerTipoView =(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerTipoView);
    nomeTabellaGen=nomeTabella;

    spinnerTipoViewArray=new ArrayList<String>();

    if(addingRecord==true||tableDataChart==null)
        spinnerTipoViewArray=CpmAnalysisParams.tipoViewAdding();
    else    
        spinnerTipoViewArray=CpmAnalysisParams.tipoView();

    spinnerTipoViewArrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner, spinnerTipoViewArray);
    spinnerTipoViewArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerTipoView.setAdapter(spinnerTipoViewArrayAdapter);
    if(addingRecord==true||tableDataChart==null)
        spinnerTipoView.setOnTouchListener(SpinnerTipoViewOnTouch);

    spinnerTipoView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {


            if(arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString().toUpperCase().equals("CHART")){

                try {
                    eTxtUrl=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUrl);
                    eTxtUrl.setEnabled(false);
                    eTxtUrl.setFocusable(false);
                    spinnerCategoria=(CustomSpinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerCategoria);
                    spinnerCategoria.setEnabled(true);
                    spinnerTabella=(CustomSpinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerTabella);
                    spinnerTabella.setEnabled(true);
                    spinnerAscissa=(CustomSpinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerAscissa);
                    spinnerAscissa.setEnabled(true);
                    buildSpinnerAreaDisplay();
                    buildSpinnerCategoria();
                    if(nomeTabellaGen!=""){
                        buildSpinnerTabella(nomeTabellaGen);
                    }
                    else
                        buildSpinnerTabella("");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            else if(arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString().equals("Seleziona tipo view")){
                buildSpinnerAreaDisplay();
                buildGrafConfigSpinnerDisabled();

            }
            else{
                try {
                    eTxtUrl=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUrl);
                    eTxtUrl.setEnabled(true);
                    eTxtUrl.setFocusable(true);
                    spinnerCategoria=(CustomSpinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerCategoria);
                    spinnerCategoria.setOnTouchListener(null);
                    spinnerCategoria.setEnabled(false);
                    spinnerTabella=(CustomSpinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerTabella);
                    spinnerTabella.setEnabled(false);
                    spinnerTabella.setOnTouchListener(null);
                    spinnerAscissa=(CustomSpinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerAscissa);
                    spinnerAscissa.setEnabled(false);
                    spinnerAscissa.setOnTouchListener(null);
                    buildSpinnerAreaDisplay();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


    });


}
```

I don't know what is wrong because when I select browser, then chart, then browser another time, my edit text is still disabled.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you working with visiblity of your EditText, when you select the CHART  , then hide your EditText , and when you deselect it , bring it VISIBLE, without trying each time finding view by its id in every select item event

Comment: because i need my users see the edittext. i dont want to make it invisibile, i want it's only disabled

Comment: your toUpperCase() method make , problem. check it.

Comment: so make your edittext visible at first time , and the item is not selected by default :), and after that , the user will understand that the edittext is hidden after selecting the value on the spinner

Comment: i'm not a freelancer, i have to follow my boss' dispositions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable editing - have you tried using:

```
eTxtUrl.setFocusableInTouchMode(true)
```

instead of (or after) that line:

```
eTxtUrl.setFocusable(true);
```